# hyperledger fabric v0.6 modify Data in RockDB or Database

Tags: security, membership, audit, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

Since the concept of blockchain is not support modification. All data that being write to Ledger will not support changing. I want to test on changing data value that store in Ledger. I try to find ways around on how to change data, but I couldn't an exact one. I know that Hyperledger Fabric v0.6, Data is stored in RockDB.

Really Appreciate if someone could help to figure out that part. Because I also want to know that it really support un-modification.

Also Auditor will involve in checking Data changing. I also still cannot get clear answer on What's Auditor?
How to configure Auditor in Fabric v0.6?

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to a peer or hack into a peer, you can tamper with the data. The power of blockchain is not that the data on a single peer is unmodifiable, it's that modification can be detected since the hash chain and signatures would not be correct if the data was tampered. This peer would not be able to change other peers, or convince other peers of the accuracy of the modified data. The integrity of the overall blockchain would remain.